# Java access parent variable returns null

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm trying to access a parent's variable from child class, but it returns null.

I explicitly called parent's constructor and assigned the value in there, but I get null values in child class.

I'm wondering if this could work or we will have to use `Getter/Setter`?

```java
public class Parent {
    public static String name;

    public Parent() {
        System.out.println("Parent constructor is called");
        this.name = "Adam";
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent{
    static final String parentName = Parent.name;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child c = new Child();
        System.out.println(parentName);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Parent constructor is called
null
```

Comment: You should read up on the modifiers and initialization order. In your case `parentName` will be initialized when the `Child` _class_ is loaded (i.e. the class definition) and at that point `Parent.name` will also be null. Setting that _static_ field in the constructor happens later when the instance is created but doing that is wrong anyway since `name` is not an instance field but a class level field. Remove the `static` keywords for a start and change the assignment to `parentName = name`. You then need to get the `parentName` from the `Child` instance you created, i.e. `c.parentName`.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, if you want to access parent variable name, then remove final keyword from Child class and assign Parent.Name to parentName variable after you create instance of Child class. The value is getting null because you are trying to assign Parent variable's value before object creation.

```
public class Parent {
    public static String name;

    public Parent() {
        System.out.println("Parent constructor is called");
        this.name = "Adam";
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent{
    static String parentName;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child c = new Child();
        parentName = Parent.name;
        System.out.println(parentName);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely correct: "The value is getting null because you are trying to assign Parent variable's value before object creation."  Thank you for editing your initial response.  +1 after your changes :)  There are actually several different - equally important - issues here, 
 Hopefully the OP will carefully read Thomas's comment above and take it to heart.